# Free cloning app proposal for Android 9

Tags: applications, parallel-apps

My phone is Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact - G8441 ruining on Android 9 with NO ROOT...
I would like to run multiple (up to 4 different accounts) - ideally each with it's separate PlayStore Account and with WhatsApp / Viber / Telegram apps... I also really need some app that has an option to install an app directly from ".apk file" and just install it in one of the "containers" (without installing it on the "main" phone account)

I've tried Parallel Space and it's "Incognito Installation feature", but some apps just won't load when installed incognito and it kept crashing etc...

All others "App Cloning" apps appear to be one same app with different colors/logos...

I am not an Android expert, so if you can give me some pointers - I would really appreciate any advice !

Answer (score 0):

The apps you mentioned are linked to a phone number. So any attempt to clone them is going to be unsatisfactory.  Dual sims is one way to have two accounts.

You can have multiple play store accounts, but can only be logged into one. And most, not all, apps generally use the current account.